# My Validating an input field with only characters and spaces allowed. I not that familiar with regex this is just for

Tags: javascript

The contact name input area cannot be left empty and can only have characters and spaces. I'm not that familiar with regex and my online research so far hasn't come up with a simplified explanation on how to do this.

The Regex string I have come across so far is: ^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*$

But I'm not advanced enough to know how to write this as script? Can anyone help.

Thanks.

```js
var contact_name = document.getElementById('contact');

function validate() {

if (contact_name == "") {
        alert("Name name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
     
*Do I need a new function, or can I insert script here?
```

```html
    <p>Contact Person: <input id="contact" name="contact" type="text" placeholder="Type Full Name here"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure in your regex, so I googled a little and found this one, which looks good: `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/`. The first issue is where you're trying to compare `contact_name == ""`: `contact_name` is an element, not input's value, so it should be `contact_name.value === ""` instead (and I recommend to use strict equality `===` here). And finally you can check input's value validity via regex using `regex.test(contact_name.value)`, which returns boolean. The solution is rather simple, but if anything isn't clear - feel free to ask.

```js
var contact_name = document.getElementById('contact');
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;

function validate() {
  var isValid = true;
  if (contact_name.value === "" || !regex.test(contact_name.value)) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  alert("Is valid: " + isValid)
}
```

```html
<p>Contact Person: <input id="contact" name="contact" type="text" placeholder="Type Full Name here"></p>
<button onclick="validate()">validate</button>
```

Comment: So this is combining validation for both a need for input and for the input to be only characters and spaces?

Comment: @T.Gowing, yes, you already wrote the first part of validation, I just added the second part. We can write 2 "if statements" if needed, but in my answer I combined them in one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contact_name = document.getElementById('contact');
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;

function validate() {
  var isValid = true;
  if (contact_name.value === "" || !regex.test(contact_name.value)) {
    isValid = false;
  }
  alert("Is valid: " + isValid)
}
```